# How to select a specific class when others have the same name?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, while-loop, show-hide

Ok, so say I have got a table that looks like this:

```
<table class="first-table" border="1" width="400px">
   <tr>
       <td><?php echo $row_cond['title']; ?></td>
       <td><a class="more" href="#" onClick="slideup()">Display More</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="full_result">
       <td colspan="2"><?php echo $row_cond['description']; ?></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

You can see I have got a link that when clicked will call the `slideUp()` function to show or hide the tr with the "full_result" class:

```
var command = false;
function slideup() { //New function SlidUp
    if (command == false){
         $('.full_result').fadeIn();
         $('.more').text('Display More');
         command = true;
    }else{
         $('.full_result').hide();
         $('.more').text('Display Less');
         command = false;
    }
}
```

So the trick is, this is in a while loop and is repeated many times.  So how do I make it so that when I click on the link, only the class "full_result" is shown in the table where I clicked the link.

At the moment when I click the button in any table, all the classes show and hide at the same time.

**My Solution**

```
$('.full_result').hide();
$(".more").on("click",function(){
    $('.more').html('Display More');
    $('.full_result').hide();
    $(this).parents("tr").next().next().fadeIn();
    $(this).html('');
    return false; //This stops the page jumping to the top of the page when I click the link
});
```

Comment: might be you can think of using `ID` rather than `class` for your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your JS code this way and remove "onClick" attribute from ".more" links:

```
var command = false;
$(".more").on("click",function(){
    if (command == false){
         $(this).parents("tr").next().fadeIn();
         $(this).html('Display Less');
         command = true;
    }else{
          $(this).parents("tr").next().hide();
         $(this).html('Display More');
         command = false;
    }
});
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tZVFK/)

**EDIT**

If you have more than one row below row "`.more`" you can use `.nextAll()` to show/hide all next rows. And just use `.slideToggle()` to avoid using "`var command`". This code:

```
$(".more").on("click",function(){    
         $(this).parents("tr").nextAll().fadeToggle();
         if($(this).html()=="Display More") $(this).html('Display Less');            
         else $(this).html('Display More');
});
```

See new [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WBdqr/)

Comment: Hi, this one seems to work best out of all of them, however it still doesnt work.  I should have said that my table im using actaully has 3 <tr></tr> sections and this code seems to show and hide the second one when I need the third one showing and hiding.  What bit do I need to change for this to work?

Comment: I think u may run into  problems with the `command` var in this solution.  It will be set to true for a `.more` click but if you click on another `.more` without closing the first instance the var will still be true and nothing will happen.

Comment: Ah, I didnt notice that.  Is there a way around that?

Comment: In this case try to use .nextAll() instead .next()

Comment: Just comes down to finding a different way to determine if the relevant `.full_result` is open or not.  Multiple ways to do it.  I have one solution posted below.  You could also add an 'open' class to the element and check for that.

Comment: Ok, iv figured it out, ill put the code up top, but iv kinda cheated, however it works.  Plus its better cause now you can only view one at a time which is what I would have wanted anyway.

Comment: Im not sure if everyone would agree with that solution, but it works for me.  I know its not exactly what I wanted, but its not hugly important for my site

Comment: @Ben, I've complemented my answer, so you can avoid usung "command" var. And yes, brains911 was right. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a common class on table and refer to the required tr as below

1) have some common class on table tag. for ex: 
2) script should be as below. with this you dont have to call inline functions.

```
$(document).on('click', '.tr-hidable .more',function(){
  if (command == false){
    $(this).parents('tr-hidable').first().find('full-result').fadeIn();
    $(this).text('Display More');
    command = true;
  }else{
    $(this).parents('tr-hidable').first().find('full-result').fadeOut();
    $(this).text('Display Less');
    command = false;
  }
});
```

or if we dont have any dynamic elements, we can replace the first line of script with below line and all the remining script will remain same.

```
$('.tr-hidable .more').on('click',function(){
```

Hope, it helps!

Comment: There was no mentioning of dynamic inserted elements. There should be no reason to bind to the `document` having all click events on the `tr` bubbling up all the way. OP already stated `at the moment when I click the button in any table, all the classes show and hide at the same time` This would indicate that the binding of the click event is already correct but the exepcted behaviour is not.

Comment: I think thats a better approach to bind events to document, which will   make it work on dynamic inserted elements as well. Other way also works, But i thought its a better approach.

Comment: @perm: Unless there are dynamic elements, binding to the `document` because you `may` have dynamic elements is not very practical. Having all events bubble up all the way to the `document` `just-in-case` is very in-efficient if it is not needed. `Only` if dynamic elements need events attached would you use `on()` 's dynamic binding syntax and even then one should bind to the closest static element not `document` unless there is no other choice off course.

Comment: @Francois: Yeah, got your point and updated my answer. Thankyou for the info.

Answer (score 0):

try this

***HTML CODE***

```
<table class="first-table" border="1" width="400px">
   <tr>
       <td><?php echo $row_cond['title']; ?></td>
       <td><a class="more" href="#">Display More</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="full_result">
       <td colspan="2"><?php echo $row_cond['description']; ?></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

***JS CODE***

```
$('.more').on('click', function(){
    slideup();

});
var command = true;
function slideup() { //New function SlidUp
    alert('ok');
    if (command == true){
         $('.full_result').fadeIn(400);
         $('.more').text('Display More');
         command = false;
    }else{
         $('.full_result').hide();
         $('.more').text('Display Less');
         command = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can try:

```
$('.more').on('click',function(){
    var text = $(this).text() === "Display More" ? "Display Less" : "Display More";
    $(this).text(text)
           .closest('table').children('.full_result').fadeToggle();
});
```